# Which controller should I put @notifications in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Imagine a typical, modern web app - where in the navbar or some navigation element that runs along the top there is a `notifications` menu where it tells the user how many notifications they have received since last visiting.

It also may have a dropdown menu that they can clear off existing notifications or just view them.

Given that these notifications need to be present across all views, where should I put the logic for that? In my `ApplicationController`? That feels wrong, for some reason - but I can't see any other explanation.

Also, should I put the actual partials within the generic `/shared/` folder?

For those apps that have a `Dashboard` controller (i.e. a non-restful resource) that just acts as the central hub for a lot of this info, what's the best way to approach this? In terms of structuring partials that will be included in the `Dashboard`.

**Edit 1**

Building off of the answers given by both Kevin and Collin below, I need to go a bit further.

They recommend the `Facade` pattern as explained by Sandi Metz via [Thoughtbot here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers).

However, this is my issue. In my `application.html.erb`, I have a partial being rendered - `<%= render partial: "shared/navbar" %>.` In that partial, I want to be able to call somethings (e.g. that `@notifications`). How would I access that instance variable and other shared variables/resources on other partials that would be declared in this `facades/dashboard.rb`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Facade pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FacadePattern) as described in [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers).

See the section on: **Only instantiate one object in the controller**.

They even use notifications on a dashboard in their example. :)

Comment: I really like the direction you are going. Do you happen to have an answer to my comments on Collin's answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember a couple of things here:

First, only put this logic in your `ApplicationController` if it's the only place it could possibly go. Since this notifications menu is more than likely persisted across the entire application, that's probably where it belongs.

Secondly, you can implement this Facade while still keeping your `DashboardsController` quite RESTful. Controllers should only be responsible for instantiating a single object, right? Thus, it makes sense to do something like this:

```
app/controllers/dashboards_controller.rb

class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @dashboard = Dashboard.new(current_user)
  end
end


app/facades/dashboard.rb

class Dashboard
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def new_status
    @new_status ||= Status.new
  end

  def statuses
    Status.for(user)
  end

  def notifications
    @notifications ||= user.notifications
  end

  private

  attr_reader :user
end


app/views/dashboards/show.html.erb

<%= render 'profile' %>
<%= render 'groups', groups: @dashboard.group %>

<%= render 'statuses/form', status: @dashboard.new_status %>
<%= render 'statuses', statuses: @dashboard.statuses %>
```

The Dashboard model gives you back all the pertinent information you need, and your controller gets to focus on a single entity. Beautiful!

**UPDATE**

In order to use your `@dashboard` instance variable inside of any partials, it's recommended you render it with a local, which is essentially a designated variable for use inside of a partial.

[Here's a great link](http://thepugautomatic.com/2013/05/locals/) on how to get started passing locals to a partial.

Comment: What would my `/views/dashboard/index.html.erb` look like? I am liking the direction you have gone, but how/why would I be using that `@dashboard` object? I also don't have a `Dashboard` model, it literally is just a controller and a set of views that I use to display info from all the other resources within the app.

Comment: Or more appropriately, here is the issue. In my `application.html.erb`, I have a partial being rendered - `<%= render partial: "shared/navbar" %>`. In that partial, I want to be able to call somethings (e.g. that `@notifications`). How would I access that instance variable and other `shared variables/resources` on other partials that would be declared in this `facades/dashboard.rb`?

Comment: Right. You can create a Dashboard model that's a PORO (plain old Ruby object) that doesn't need to be database-backed at all. This is a best practice, because you shouldn't be concerned with business logic in your Rails controllers, and they should ultimately only be instantiating a single entity. I've updated my answer to show how something like `views/dashbard/show.html.erb` could look, as well as how to use it in a partial.

Comment: I understand that Collin, the issue I am struggling with is how do I abstract that away from the `dashboard` facade (i.e. in a general shared partial that is called from the application layout, not within a Dashboard view). That's what I was trying to get at in my comments and updated question. All you did was pasted more code from the Thoughtbot article which doesn't really address my issue. That would work if I am using the `DashboardsController` as the base with which I am calling all the partials within. In my case, I am calling them from my `application.html.erb`.

Comment: I pasted more code from the Thoughtbot article because I thought it accurately addressed your question. In any case, why not just call a new `Dashboard` model from your `ApplicationController` if you want it to persist across a partial included from within said controller?

Comment: Hrmm...I don't want to use `ApplicationController` if I don't have to. That's my issue.

Comment: If this functionality is persisted across the entire application, I really think you'll have to. Otherwise you're going to have to replicate those inclusions in every single entity, which violates DRY.